# How to set text position programmatically in EditText class?

Tags: android

Does smomeone know how I set the scrollbar position in an EditView programmatically.

I'm appending the text during special events but I want the EditView to scroll down to the latest text added so it'll be visible. But default the scrollbar does not move automatically when appending text.

/ Henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call yourEditText.scrollBy(int x, int y) after you added text to your EditText. Maybe you have to test some values until you find the appropriate values

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But isn't there any "nice looking way" to select a Y that' fits. I.e. just "trying a few values", couldn't that mess up future compatibility for different screen sizes etc?

Comment: then just use a value high enough to always scroll to the bottom. e.g. Integer.MAX_VALUE